# Getting specific part of output in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have an output from a shell script like this:

**aaa.sh output**

```
     Tue Mar 04 01:00:53 2014
     Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
     Tue Mar 04 07:21:52 2014
     Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
     Tue Mar 04 13:17:16 2014
     Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
     Tue Mar 04 16:56:01 2014
     SQL> ALTER DISKGROUP fra  ADD DISK  '/dev/rhdisk20' 
     Wed Mar 05 00:03:42 2014
     Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
     Wed Mar 05 04:13:39 2014
     Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
     Tue Mar 05 05:56:07 2014
     GMON querying group 3 at 10 for pid 18, osid 27590856
     GMON querying group 3 at 11 for pid 18, osid 27590856
```

I need to get the part, beginning from today's date:

```
     Wed Mar 05 00:03:42 2014
     Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
     Wed Mar 05 04:13:39 2014
     Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
     Tue Mar 05 05:56:07 2014
     GMON querying group 3 at 10 for pid 18, osid 27590856
     GMON querying group 3 at 11 for pid 18, osid 27590856
```

Comment: I'm not a professional on bash. So i need a clear solution.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark `man awk` or `man sed` has all the information you need to find a solution. Also `man date`. If you still can't manage to do it out you should add your attempt to the question.

Comment: The solution is to become a little professional on bash. That does need several hours of reading [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), [gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the date in the correct format like this:

```
today=$(date +'%a %b %d')
```

and then search for it like this:

```
grep "$today" aaa.sh
```

If there are lines from today without a date, such as your GMON lines, you could add `-A` to say how many lines **after** the match you want and use a big number:

```
grep -A 999999 "$today" aaa.sh
```

If you are on AIX and there is no -A option, use sed like this:

```
today=$(date +'%a %b %d')
sed -n "/${today}/,$ p" aaa.sh
```

**Explanation:**

That says store today's date in the variable `today` in the format "Wed Mar 05". Then search, without printing anything (`-n`) till you find that date, From that point on, till the end of file (`$`) print all lines (`p`).

Comment: How to do that in AIX? Because there is no -A parameter in that.

Comment: I got an error:
aaa.sh[10]: Wed:  not found.
sed: 0602-410 The first regular expression cannot be null.

My date format is like that("Wed Mar 05")

Comment: Try again, I added braces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
  tail -n 7 filename
```

for getting the desired output . It will basically give you the last seven lines of the text file named `filename` .

For getting solution from  today's date you can use :

```
 k=$(date +"%a %b %d")
 g=$(grep -nr "$k" in|cut -f1 -d:|head -1)
 total=$(wc -l<in)
 l=`expr $total - $g + 1
 tail -n$l in
```

Comment: I need the part from beginning of today's date. There may be much more lines.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an easy solution:

Get `date` to output the date in a format that would match the date in the file (check `man date` on formatting options). Since we don't want to match the hours/minutes/seconds we have to call `date` twice: once for the weekday/month/day half and once for the year half on the end of the full date. Between these two halves we match the horus/minutes/seconds with `.*` regex.

Then do:

```
aaa.sh | grep -E '`date --only-weekday-month-day`.*`date --only-year`' -A 999999
```

Answer (score 1):

though I am using answer by NewWorld it can be modified as,

convert output of date similar to your file format

suppose in variable 'D'you get that output

```
sed '1,/${D}/d' aaa.sh
```

that will output all lines after match date match.

example: suppose you get `D="Wed Mar 05 00:03:42 2014"`

output will be as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have another question, how to do the same thing in AIX? Because syntax is different.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark the above solution prints all lines after the pattern match, it excludes the first line. Just FYI

Comment: You can use sed -n "/${D}/,$ p" aaa.sh to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`sed -n '/Wed Mar 05/,$p' aaa.sh`

Here `-n` means "don't print anything unless specified to".
First appearance of a line that matches the expression /Wed\ Mar\ 05/ till the end of the file, will be printed(`p`)"

Comment: Just a friendly word of advice... you do not need to escape the spaces with slashes. And you do not need to specify `-e` when there is only one piece of code to execute since sed knows what it is and what to do with it.